# Magento option price layout modification

Tags: php, html, magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

[image]

This is the dropdown list layout i got for my magento right now, but is it possible to move the numbers (price) to the very right? and let the 14k Yellow stay still so it's like

```
14k Yellow                             +1.00$
```

Doesn't look nice but just want to see if i can edit the layout.

Comment: On which URL you are getting this drop down?

Comment: every "price", the numbers

Answer (score 1):

Activate your template-hints, see which template is used. Move to the template search for the  and simply change the values.